# Alter table commands take so long to execute

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, hierarchy, database-normalization

I'm trying to create 4 table hierarchy - Sport Category, League, Team and Player. Till this moment this is what I have created:

```
      -- Create PLAYER table
create table PLAYER
(
  PLAYER_ID           INT not null,
  NAME_OF_PLAYER         VARCHAR(36) not null,
  NUMBER_OF_PLAYER      INT not null,
  TEAM_ID                   INT not null
) ;

alter table PLAYER
  add constraint PLAYER_PK primary key (PLAYER_ID);

alter table PLAYER MODIFY COLUMN PLAYER_ID INT auto_increment;

alter table PLAYER
  add constraint PLAYER_UK unique (NAME_OF_PLAYER, TEAM_ID);


     -- Create TEAM table
create table TEAM
(
  TEAM_ID           INT not null,
  NAME_OF_TEAM          VARCHAR(36) not null,
  LEAGUE_ID         INT not null
) ;

alter table TEAM
  add constraint TEAM_PK primary key (TEAM_ID);

alter table TEAM MODIFY COLUMN TEAM_ID INT auto_increment;

alter table TEAM
  add constraint TEAM_UK unique (NAME_OF_TEAM);



    -- Create LEAGUE table
create table LEAGUE
(
  LEAGUE_ID           INT not null,
  NAME_OF_LEAGUE          VARCHAR(36) not null,
  SPORT_CATEGORY_ID         INT not null
) ;

alter table LEAGUE
  add constraint LEAGUE_PK primary key (LEAGUE_ID);

alter table LEAGUE MODIFY COLUMN LEAGUE_ID INT auto_increment;

alter table LEAGUE
  add constraint LEAGUE_UK unique (NAME_OF_LEAGUE);



   -- Create Sport_Category table
create table SPORT_CATEGORY
(
  SPORT_CATEGORY_ID           INT not null,
  NAME_OF_CATEGORY          VARCHAR(36) not null
) ;

alter table SPORT_CATEGORY
  add constraint SPORT_CATEGORY_PK primary key (SPORT_CATEGORY_ID);



alter table SPORT_CATEGORY MODIFY COLUMN SPORT_CATEGORY_ID INT auto_increment;



alter table SPORT_CATEGORY
  add constraint SPORT_CATEGORY_UK unique (NAME_OF_CATEGORY);



alter table PLAYER
  add constraint PLAYER_FK foreign key (TEAM_ID)
  references TEAM (TEAM_ID);

alter table TEAM
  add constraint TEAM_FK1 foreign key (LEAGUE_ID)
  references LEAGUE (LEAGUE_ID);


alter table LEAGUE
  add constraint LEAGUE_FK1 foreign key (SPORT_CATEGORY_ID)
  references SPORT_CATEGORY (SPORT_CATEGORY_ID);
```

When I execute the this sql file, it takes like 15 seconds to finish. With some testing I noticed that alter table statements make it slower. Is this normal for this kind of relation tables? Is it because of the complexity of the tables?

I'm new to working with relations but very enthusiastic about it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Four questions is sort of the definition of "too broad".

Comment: @GordonLinoff I agree, you are right.

Comment: I ran your queries on an instance of MySQL 8.0 on my laptop, and the total time reported by the profiler was 0.174 seconds. The longest single statement was 0.024 seconds. I have to wonder if you are running on a very old computer, or if you have a computer that is running other demanding software.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you add the keys with alter table instead of inline within the create table?

Comment: @BillKarwin That's very interesting. I just tested it again and it takes a while. What I'm doing is: I start MySQL from XAMPP and then on another prompt I execute the sql. Now at least i know the problem is from my side. Thank you.

Comment: @Shadow I'm working on university project and we just learned about alter table. So that's why. I'm pretty new to SQL.

Comment: Most of your ALTERs are unnecessary, because you can define primary keys, column options, and indexes as you CREATE TABLE. Sometimes I see foreign keys added to tables using ALTER because you can't create a foreign key to a table you haven't defined yet. So to avoid needing to create tables in a specific order, some people define all their tables without foreign keys, then after all tables are created, do another pass to add foreign keys with ALTER TABLE.